# any hints on how I can turn this layout into a two column one on screens min-width(786px)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to turn the main content area of my css into a two column layout on screen sizes 786px or smaller.. but instead it switches directly from 2 rows to 1 single column. I've tried moving some of the flexbox outside of the media queries but to no avail. I do have my flex direction set to column on smaller screens but it doesn't seem to apply when running the code.

```css
/* -- Base Element Styles -- */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color:peachpuff;
  margin: 0;
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  color: lightslategray;
}
h2 {
  color: lightslategray;
}
h3,
a {
  color: lightslategrey;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  padding: 8px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.unit .p {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* -- Base Layout Styles -- */

.main-header,
  .main-nav,
  .intro-unit,
  .container,
  .container-2,
  .main-footer,
  .footer-nav,
  .footer-list {
      display: flex;
     
  }
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .intro-unit {
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      
  }
  .container,
  .container-2 {
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .main-footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .footer-list,
  .footer-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

.main-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:lightsalmon;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
main {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
.name {
  font-size: 1.35em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.intro-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.main-nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav-link{
  text-align: center;
}
.main-nav a {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
.nav-link {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.container-2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;  
}
.logo {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.footer-list {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
/* -- Layout Containers -- */
h1 a {
  padding: 0px;
}
.intro-unit,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.intro-unit {
 color:lightslategray;
 background:wheat;
 padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
 margin-top: 150px;
}
.main-footer {
  color: floralwhite;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 14px 10px 11px 10px;
} 
.container {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.container-2 {
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;  
}
.unit {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
/* -- Media Queries -- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container,
  .container-2 {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .intro-unit {
    margin: 7rem auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .intro-unit,
  .container,
  .container-2 {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1150px;
  }
  .intro-unit {
    margin: 5rem auto;
  }
}

/* -- Flex Box -- */

 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .intro-unit {
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
 }

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
   .main-header {
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: space-between;
   }
   .main-nav {
     flex-direction: row;
   }
   .intro-unit {
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
   }
   .container,
   .container-2 {
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: space-around;
   }
   .footer-list {
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: space-between;
   }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Webpage</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-header">
        <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Cole Smith</a></h1>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <header class="intro-unit">
        <img class="logo" src="img/profile-picture.svg" alt="profile picture">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <p>Hi, my name is Cole Smith I am an aspiring front/backend Web Designer! I am currently learning web design through Treehouse Tech and this is one of my projects.</p>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="intro-title" id="portfolio">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    </div>

    <main class="container">
        <div class="unit-1 unit">
            <img src="img/marketing.svg" alt=" image representing a marketing page">
            <h2>Marketing Page</h2>
            <p>This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for specific business i'm interested in.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="unit-2 unit">
            <img src="img/search-app.svg" alt="image representing a travel webpage design">
            <h2>Search Page</h2>
            <p>This project searches through a specific database to find information that the user is trying to look up.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="unit-3 unit">
            <img src="img/travel-app.svg" alt="image representing a favorite spot-styled webpage">
            <h2>travel app</h2>
            <p>This project compares travel times based on different transportation methods and tells you the best one.</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <div class="container-2">
        <div class="unit-4 unit">
            <img src="img/fav-spot.svg" alt="image representing a photo gallery webpage">
            <h2>Map of Favorite Spots</h2>
            <p>This project uses mapping apis to plot points for my favorite spots in the city for a do-it-yourself walking tour.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="unit-5 unit">
            <img src="img/photo-gallery.svg" alt="image representing a calculator webpage">
            <h2>Photo Gallery</h2>
            <p>This project shows pictures from a recent trip to the viewer and allows them to easily navigate through photos.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="unit-6 unit">
            <img src="img/calculator.svg" alt="Image representing calculator-styled page">
            <h2>Calculator</h2>
            <p>Someone can enter the numbers they want and press the big blue button and get the result.</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    
    
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="footer-div">
            <h3 class="footer-title">Contact</h3>
            <p id="contact">If you're interested in chatting or want more information about what i've been working on, i'd love to hear from you!</p>
            <p>Phone: 1 (303) 4040</p>
            <p>Email: cole.smith.code@gmail.com</p>
            <ul class="footer-list">
                <li class="footer-nav"><a href="#">Cole Smith</a></li>
                <li class="footer-nav"><a href="#">Back To Top</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is is that you want to go from 3 to 2 to 1 column layouts as your decrease screen width?

Comment: I would use CSS grid instead of flexbox for this. In larger screen you can create your current layout and in smaller screen you can create a layout with two columns and the rows needed

Comment: Check out this link to learn more about dynamic grid layouts where you don't need media queries: https://css-tricks.com/intrinsically-responsive-css-grid-with-minmax-and-min/

Comment: @TylerMorales yes that is what I want to do. I will check out that link, thanks for both your guys help.